# How to sync light to the current song with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to make an LED attached to my Raspberry Pi blink in sync with the music playing on the Raspberry.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the current level of volume of the track which is in line audio. How can I do this?

I use Raspbian.